# Least distance sorting

Tags: sorting

There are 10 Egyptian stone statues standing in a row in an art gallery hall. A new curator wants to move them so that the statues are ordered by their height. How should this be done to minimize the total distance that the statues are moved? You may assume for simplicity that all the statues have different heights.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: [The same question about sorting stone](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18568/sorting-stone-problem) has been closed.